# Fetch a single result from a MySQL Database using PDO

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

Okay, for starters, I have a Table in MySQL with the columns "barcode","description", and "quantity". I have two pages, 1 HTML and 1 PHP. The HTML has a form in it to accept a barcode scan, or manual text entry. Based on that entry, I want it to return a row, starting with the barcode that was entered in on the HTML form. So far, I can enter anything and it will return the whole table.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<head>
<font color="00CC00">
<title>Search</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="000000">

<h2>Find Product</h2>

<form name="search" method="post" action="Barcode Search.php">
<input type="text" name="find" placeholder="Click to Scan" /> 


<input type="submit" name="search" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Short, sweet and to the point!
The .PHP look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<title>Inventory List</title>

<body bgcolor="000000">
<font color="00cc00">

 <?php 
//Table
echo "<table style='border: solid 1px green;'>";
echo "<tr><th>Barcode</th><th>Description</th><th>Quantity</th></tr>";

class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator {
    function __construct($it) {
        parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY);
    }

    function current() {
        return "<td style='width:150px;border:1px solid green;'>" . parent::current(). "</td>";
    }

    function beginChildren() {
        echo "<tr>";
    }

    function endChildren() {
        echo "</tr>" . "\n";
    }
} 
//Connection Info
$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "XXXX";
$password = "XXXXX";
$dbname = "test";


//Connection Started, Data pulled
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM inventory ");
    $stmt->execute();

// set the resulting array to associative
    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) {
        echo $v;
    }
}

    //Error Check

catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
// Take Text entry and fetch the SQL Row


//Kill Connection 
$conn = null;
echo "</table>";
?> 
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd very much appreciate a point in the right direction!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM inventory` selects *everything* from the `inventory` table, no refinements or limitations. I'm guessing you want something like this:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE barcode = ? LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bindParam("s", $_POST["find"]); // 's' means it's a string
$stmt->execute();
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: Doh! Faster typer, better answer!

Comment: hopefully no one gets to that page without posting the `find` field

Comment: Thanks! 
So I'd just replace the existing 
    $stmt=$conn and $stmt->execute();
lines with this? what is the "?" for?

Comment: @CodenameJinn Keep the `execute()` line (see edit). The `?` is the placeholder for the param you bind on the next line (see the link to the documentation).

Comment: Much appreciated! I didn't understand the syntax, but it makes sense now!

Answer (score -1):

The problem is you've done a `SELECT * FROM inventory` with no `WHERE` statement, so you'll get everything from that table. What you need to do is add in a binding parameter, use this:

```
//Connection Started, Data pulled
try {
    $barcodeValue = isset($_POST['find']) ? $_POST['find'] : false;
    if($barcodeValue === false) throw new PDOException("No Barcode Value");
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE `barcode` = :barcodeToSearchFor");
    $stmt->bindValue(':barcodeToSearchFor', $barcodeValue );
    $stmt->execute();

// set the resulting array to associative
    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) {
        echo $v;
    }
}
```