# Fatal error: Class 'TableRows' not found in

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I got an error like this

> Fatal error: Class 'TableRows' not found in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/colorlib-search-23/test.php on line 15

Here is my code :

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users"); 
    $stmt->execute();

    // set the resulting array to associative
    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) { 
        echo $v;
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
```

Checked names of the database table and all, copy-pasted other code but still it's not working

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users"); 
    $stmt->execute();

    // set the resulting array to associative
    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) { 
        echo $v;
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
```

This error should not come.

Comment: Where do you define the TableRows class?

Comment: Do you include an autoloader, or the individual php files?

Comment: No, I have not created any classes.  I do have only one file index.php which code is written above

Comment: Hey Nigel i have not included anything the code is only as per above

Comment: Where do you expect `TableRows` to come from? For example, [`RecursiveArrayIterator`](https://www.php.net/manual/class.recursivearrayiterator.php) is a built-in PHP class but `TableRows` is not. It would have to come from your code or some other 3rd-party library

Comment: I have no idea Phil I have not created any classes and there is no any more code or files than above

Comment: Hi phil i have not use any third party library

Comment: So what you're saying is you copied this code from somewhere but have no idea how it's supposed to work. Correct?

Comment: Try replacing the `foreach` with `foreach($stmt->fetchAll() as $v) { 
        print_r( $v);
    }`

Comment: NO i wrote a sample code myself and it gave me same error and i copied the PDO code from w3school even its giving me the same error

Comment: Are you following a tutorial or something? What inspired you to write `new TableRows(...)` into your code?

Comment: You no need to use tableRows class. Write code which requires to get what you want. That's it.

Comment: Looks very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27930150/fetch-a-single-result-from-a-mysql-database-using-pdo) except that one actually defines `TableRows`

Answer (score 5):

There is a certain extremely harmful article on the Internet telling that you need whatever TableRows class to work with PDO. *Which is extremely rubbish.*

In reality you don't need anything like this. **Just use a regular foreach**

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM users"); 
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

At this point you have a conventional PHP array that can be iterated over as any other array using `foreach` or encoded using `json_encode` or used any other way

```
// iterate over rows
foreach($data as $row) { 
    // iterate over values in each row
    foreach($row as $v) { 
        echo $v, " ";
    }
    echo "<br>"\n;
}
```

Comment: you are missing the semi colon at the end of first code paragraph. $data = $stmt ........  Great answer!