# Having issues with incrementing a field in the database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've established a database full of movies which is connected to a HTML form of which the information is ported with PHP POST (Acts as a movie database).

When the user enters a search term (Either title, genre, year or classification) the PHP script search.php is handed the information.

This goes fine, however, i also have a column in my DB which is titled times_searched which has a default value of zero.

I feel like one of the big problems is i've just been staring at this file for too long and something simple is not apparent to me right now.

I'm very new to PHP and WebDev in general. 
I have tried issuing a second statement to execute inside the foreach loop of the TableRow class and have tried different syntaxes and attempting to bind previous statements to new statements.

```
class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator
{
    function __construct($it) 
    {
        parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY);
    }

    function current() 
    {
        return "<td style='width:150px;border:1px solid black;'>" . 
        parent::current()."</td>";
    }

    function beginChildren() 
    {
        echo "<tr>";
    }

    function endChildren() 
    {
        echo "</tr>" . "\n";
    }
}

function printAssocArray($stmt)
{
    foreach (new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) 
            as $k=>$v) {
                    echo $v;
    }
}



require 'Templates/header.php';
//DB variables
$serverName = "localhost";
$userName = "root";
$password = "";

//Post variables
$title = ($_POST['title']);
$year = ($_POST['year']);
$genre = ($_POST['genre']);
$rating = ($_POST['rating']);

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    try {
            //Create PDO object using DB variables
            $conn = new PDO(
                "mysql:host=$serverName;dbname=project_db", $userName, $password
            );
            //Set PDO error mode to exception
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            echo "<h3 class='center'>Connection Successful!</h3>";


        if (!empty($_POST['title']) && empty($_POST['genre']) 
            && empty($_POST['rating']) && empty($_POST['year'])
        ) {
                $stmt = $conn->prepare(
                    "UPDATE movies SET 
                times_searched = times_searched + 1 WHERE id = :id; 
                IN (SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title LIKE '%$title%'"
                ); 
                $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                $stmt->bindValue(':id', $result['id']);
                $stmt->execute();

         //Use function call to print information to table using TableRows
                printAssocArray($stmt);

        }elseif (!empty($_POST['genre']) && empty($_POST['rating']) 
            && empty($_POST['year']) && empty($_POST['title'])
        ) {
            $stmt = $conn->prepare(
                "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE genre LIKE '%$genre%'"
            );
            $stmt->execute();
            //Collect Result in associative array
            $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            //Use function call to print information to table using TableRows
            printAssocArray($stmt);
        }

//New Block
if (!empty($_POST['title']) && empty($_POST['genre']) 
            && empty($_POST['rating']) && empty($_POST['year'])
        ) {
            $updateQuery = "UPDATE movies SET times_searched = times_searched + 1
             WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM movies WHERE title LIKE :title)";

            $stmt = $conn->prepare($updateQuery); 
            $stmt->bindValue(':title', "%{$title}%");
            $stmt->execute();
            $outputQuery = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title LIKE :title";
            $stmt2 = $conn->prepare($outputQuery);
            $stmt2->bindValue(':title', "%{$title}%");
            $data = $stmt2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            foreach ($data as $row) {
                foreach ($row as $v) {
                    echo $v, " ";
                }
                echo "<br>",\n;
            }
```

The aim is to try and return the requested query from the database then increment the times_searched column before printing it using the TableRow Class, this should happen each time the query is run (if the page is refreshed the times_searched column should increment)

This is being used for completion of a homework project, and security is not nessacarily a factor (though use of PDO was requested).

Comment: Your update query ends at the `;`, the `IN (SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title LIKE '%$title%'` part is not valid MySQL and not needed, making that query invalid.

Comment: to my understanding, ```:id:``` could possibly be used as a marker for binding a value to use in the statement from the returned information in the subquery , is this not true in this case?

Comment: What subquery are we talking about? `IN (SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title LIKE '%$title%'` is not a valid query, remove that complete part. Besides that, it's missing a closing `)`

Comment: So the subquery should have been the section you have highlighted following the in keyword (````IN (SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title LIKE '%$title%'````) 

Why is it invalid out of interest, i did add a closing bracket too it. which resulted in a new error which has not appeared before 

```Connection Failed: SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)```

If it helps at all, when i was simply returning information and not attempting to increment it, this is how the logic flow looks.(Editted to bottom of code block)

Comment: Please read this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/57568173/285587

Comment: You're not using prepared statements correctly. All your inputs need to be bound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should either use `WHERE id = :id` (single movie item) or `WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM movies WHERE title LIKE '%$title%')` (multiple movie items), not both, not separated by a `;`.

I assume you want to use the latter (update multiple movie items), change

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare(
                    "UPDATE movies SET 
                times_searched = times_searched + 1 WHERE id = :id; 
                IN (SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title LIKE '%$title%'"
                ); 
                $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                $stmt->bindValue(':id', $result['id']);
                $stmt->execute();
```

to

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE movies SET times_searched = times_searched + 1 WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM movies WHERE title LIKE :title)"); 
$stmt->bindValue(':title',"%{$title}%");
$stmt->execute();
```

For the `// New Block` part:

Replace

```
$outputQuery = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title LIKE '%title%'";
$stmt2 = $conn->prepare($outputQuery);
$stmt2->bindValue('title', $title);
```

with

```
$outputQuery = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title LIKE :title";
$stmt2 = $conn->prepare($outputQuery);
$stmt2->bindValue(':title', "%{$title}%");
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think this won't work `'%:title%'`

Comment: @Dharman You're actually right, thanks for spotting that. Edited my answer

Comment: Code has been modified again, added to bottom of block to represent changes. 
the sql statement provided works when i use it through phpmyAdmin(replacing the like pattern with a term such as ```'%Burn%'```) it operates as expected and updates the times_searched collumn, however from the code this does not happen and no information is returned for output in both circumstances. 
The help is appreciated though!

Comment: @Wade_R Wait, you're using bindvalue again, let me update my answer

Comment: Ok, block has been edited again in the code, the counter is going up whenever the search is run from the page (Found this through phpmyAdmin). Only issue now is output and figuring out why that isn't working